# Heroku app deployed successfully but Application Error

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, plotly-dash

I'm trying to deploy a simple python Dash app to Heroku, I can deploy the app without any issues but I keep getting an Application Error when I try and view it. When I try to look at the logs through the CLI it can't find the app -- I have no understanding why!

I have created the requirements.txt file along with the Procfile file.

GitRepo for project: https://github.com/Karan-Ghatt/Covid-Data-Dash

I don't seem to understand why this is not working, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question isn't exactly clear and it'll have been better if you posted the error. if heroku can't detect your app as a python app then you should try setting the buildpack.

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I can see now that there is no detail in my post and it would be near impossible for someone to help me given the info I've provided.

I managed to get my page deployed! You can check it out here if you like :)
https://covid-data-dash.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You're welcome @Karanvir.S.G. I've checked the app, it looks good. Nice work